# How to update my jailbroken iOS 6.1 iPhone to iOS 6.1.2?

Tags: iphone, ios, jailbreak

I had jailbroken my iPhone last month when I was using iOS 6.1, and currently iOS 6.1.2 is available, which solves some battery issues (I am really suffering from these), so I want to update to iOS 6.1.2.

Would you kindly give simple steps to do that so I don't damage my device? I am not much of an expert on this, so your help is very welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is recommended to update your Jailbroken iOS device by doing full restore form iTunes. In order to preserve your apps, contacts etc. perform a backup in iTunes by right clicking on your device and selecting `back up` option.

Comment: Sir I did backup my iPhone...now what should I do...simply update via iTunes or anything else I need to do?...I no more wanna use jailbroken...thanks a lot:-)

Comment: All you need to do is to go to your iTunes, select your iOS device and click Restore iPhone... This will download a copy of latest iOS available for your device, erase your iPhone and install new iOS. After you complete that, iTunes will ask you if you would like to restore iPhone using backup that you made earlier. If you select yes then you will have your iPhone as before, but running 6.1.2 and without Jailbreak.

Comment: You are welcome. If that solved your problem, please mark my answer by clicking check mark beside it. This indicates that query has been resolved.